# tcp/ip open connection

Tags: java, android

currently i am using the following code to interact with server

```
  public String connectToserverforincomingmsgs(String phonurl, String phno)
        throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(phonurl);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setDoInput(true);

    // Allow Outputs
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.connect();
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            con.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    // give server your all parameters and values (replace param1 with you
    // param1 name and value with your one's)
    writer.write("sender_no=" + phno);

    writer.flush();

    String responseString = "";

    BufferedReader reader = null;
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String line;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        responseString = responseString.concat(line);
    }
    con.disconnect();
    return responseString;

}
```

how could i make tcp connection .right now i don't have any idea . i am new to android and java aswell so any sample code about the tcp connection would be appreciated

Comment: What protocol you want to use? Is it HTTP or you want to implement your own?

Comment: if so, you need to use Socket, as write Vivek or you can search for library, implements XMPP.

Answer (score 3):

To create a TCP Connection you need to Use Socket:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(host_name_or_ip_address, port_no);
```

To Send Data use `socket.getOutputStream()`

To Receive Data use `socket.getInputStream()`

Comment: @vivk thnx for the answer i just want to ask one more thing that is :  port number could be any or specific ;if specific how could i know that

Comment: you need to specify the port no of the server application. and the host_name_or_ip_address is your server.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace HttpURLConnection with Socket. It works pretty much the same

Comment: it shows this error "Cannot cast from URLConnection to Socket"

Comment: BOBRA you need to replace it /everywhere/

Comment: when I say 'replace', it is a little more than just replace. But the basic principles are the same.